# Como ocultar as imagens do sistema, de aplicativos de galeria firemonkey android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Preciso que as imagens usadas no sistema não apareçam no aplicativo de galeria do android, pois são imagens usadas apenas pelo sistema e ao visualiza-las alguns clientes as apagam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ocultar as imagens do seu sistema, basta criar um novo arquivo na pasta onde você colocou suas imagens, com o nome:

> .nomedia

achei a resposta
[aqui](https://www.zoomtech.com.br/saiba-como-ocultar-pasta-de-fotos-da-galeria-no-android/)

após isso as imagens não irão mais aparecer no aplicativo galeria.

Fica assim na prática

```
procedure botao_qualquer;
var
  a: TStringList;
  pasta: string;
begin

  pasta:= "caminho da pasta onde estão os arquivos";

  a:= TStringList.Create;
  a.SaveToFile(pasta+'.nomedia');
  a.Free;

end;
```